# Exclude a maven dependecie from a derived pom

Tags: java, maven

I'm using `Apache Maven 3.1.1`
In my parent pom there is a dependencie defined as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_09</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The issue is I don't want to include that dependencie in one of my derived poms. I tried the following:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

But I got both `jsf-impl-1.2_09.jar` and `jsf-impl-2.0.6.jar` jars instead of `jsf-impl-2.0.6.jar` only. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Have you checked via `mvn dependency:tree` if the dep you don't like to have is really comming via parent? Furthermore why have you inherited dependencies?

Comment: Did you tried to put the version of the jsf-impl as a property in the parent pom and then override this property in your pom?

Comment: @Nadir As far as you can see the _groupIds_ are different in these versions, since there is no way to just _ovveride_ that dependincies.

Comment: Ah indeed I missed that... So maybe try similar thing with changing the scope of the parent dependency to provided via some property?Then you will have it on classpath but on runtime there shouldnt be any conflicts. I never tried such thing but maybe it's worth to test it.

Comment: Is the dependency in the parent POM in a `<dependencies>` block or a `<dependencyManagement>` block?

Comment: did u try what @khmarbaise suggested? i wanted to suggest that myself.

Comment: The problem is that you can't exclude an inherited dependency. Can you modify the parent's pom.xml?